# spring mvc-calling to function before controller functions are called

Tags: java, spring, session, model-view-controller, controller

I want to create "pre" function. and in this function to check the session, 
When some function in controller is called, I want that my "pre" function will called before it. and from the "pre" function I will pass the user to logIn page or to do the function. 
something like this pseudo code:

```
if(!session)
   return "redirect:login";
else
   //calling to the selected function,
```

I saw some solutions to create this function, but the solution was to create it by: `@ModelAttribute`. and the problem is that with `@ModelAttribute` I didn't find any way to pass to another function in my controller. 
More than, the selected function is always called after my `@ModelAttribute` finish, 
How can I do that? there is a way to do something like this?

Comment: have a look at [Spring Security](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security)

Comment: To call a method before any request, you can use a Interceptor or Spring AOP. For login actions and role based access it is suggested to use Spring Security.

Comment: Yes but I don't want to create permissions to page, All the pages are not allowed without login, caus this I decided to use session, and when user click logout - clean the session,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using a `servlet Filter`. Here is a code snippet:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class RestrictionFilter implements Filter {
    private static final String ACCES_PUBLIC     = "/loginPage.jsp";
    private static final String ATT_SESSION_USER = "user";

    public void init( FilterConfig config ) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void doFilter( ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain ) throws IOException,
            ServletException {

        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        final HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        /**
         * check if user is not connected.
         */
        if (session.getAttribute( ATT_SESSION_USER ) == null) {
            /* Redirection to login page */
            response.sendRedirect( request.getContextPath() + ACCES_PUBLIC );
        } else {
            /** access granted for the user*/
            chain.doFilter( request, response );
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Then add the filter to your `web.xml` like below:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>RestrictionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>yourPackage.RestrictionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RestrictionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: can you add explaintion to the answer? Where I need to put it? how to use it in the controller functions.... Thanks!

Comment: "chain.doFilter" what is chain?

Comment: I've updated my answer, kindly check it and let me know if it works.

Comment: Ok thank you. In my controller don't need to add any code?

Comment: loginPage.jsp- pass to the jsp file without do the /login mapping function?

Comment: No, nothing to add to your controller, but I didn't get your last comment. Why do you mean by `login mapping function`?

Comment: I want to send objects to login page how can I do that without calling to login mapping function in my controller?

Comment: where do I need to put this class? I puted it in my controller package, but when running I got errors.

Comment: add your objects to the `request` : `request.setAttribute("param",value);`

Comment: What about get coockies object? can I do that?

Comment: Thank you! its working fine:), I'm using foundation to design the view, with the filter all of my design is looking bad, do you have any idea about it?

Comment: I'm glad it helped ! Please mark it as a correct answer (click the tick symbol beside the answer).

Comment: yes I want to mark, but the filter distroyed my view. what can i do?

Comment: Let's chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131772/discussion-between-foo-and-mitchapp

Comment: sorry but this site is block for me... Do you have another way?